# Retrieving all items from a SharePoint list and putting each field into an object

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve all of the items in a list from a SharePoint site. The fields are titled "Review Level Title", "Reviewer IDs", and "Review Level Priority". What I'm trying to do is to get the information from all three fields seperately, put them into the object I created, and then return the list with all of the objects I have created for each SharePoint item.

I have researched a lot on how to access this information from the SharePoint site, but I can not get it to work. Here is what I have created so far:

```
public List<OperationsReviewLevel> Get()
        {
            var operationsReviewLevels = new List<OperationsReviewLevel>();

            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SharePointEngineeringChangeRequest"]);
            var SPList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Review Levels");

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            ListItemCollection entries = SPList.GetItems(query);

            context.Load(entries);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach(ListItem currentEntry in entries)
            {
                operationsReviewLevels.Add(new OperationsReviewLevel(currentEntry["Review Level Title"].ToString(), currentEntry["Reviewer IDs"].ToString(), (int)currentEntry["Review Level Priority"]));
            }

            return operationsReviewLevels;

        }
```

Whenever I try this code, I receive an error saying:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

I can not find any solutions to this error (in my scenario) online, and was wondering if anyone could see what I am doing wrong in this scenario.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you tried to check it in debugging mode, to watch what is inside `entries` and what it's missing? (Normally this error is given when you forget to retrieve the properties of a client object with `context.Load` and `context.ExecuteQuery`). Just a little tip, I would write `List oList` instead of `var SPList` :)

Comment: +1! I debugged `entries` and after a lot of digging I found what the field names were listed as, going to post as an answer for future reference. Thanks for this!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comment from Alessandra Amosso under my question, I ended up debugging `entries`. It took a lot of digging in the debugger, but I was able to find what the field names were being retrieved as. Debugging your `ListItemCollection`, if you go into Data, then any entry there, and then into FieldValues, you can see what each field value should be retrieved as.

[image]

In my case, all spaces were replaces with `_x0020_` and the word priority was cut to just `priorit` due to length of the field name.

With this, I was able to change my `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach (ListItem currentEntry in entries)
{
   operationsReviewLevels.Add(new OperationsReviewLevel(currentEntry["Review_x0020_Level_x0020_Title"].ToString(), currentEntry["Reviewer_x0020_IDs"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(currentEntry["Review_x0020_Level_x0020_Priorit"].ToString())));
}
```

And it now works properly.

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Guess you're using SharePoint online, SharePoint online will remove the field special characters as staticname when creating fields, for example: `Review Level Title` will be `ReviewLevelTitle`.

Here is my test code.

```
foreach (ListItem currentEntry in entries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentEntry["ReviewLevelTitle"].ToString()+'-'+ currentEntry["ReviewerIDs"].ToString()+'-'+ currentEntry["ReviewLevelPriority"]);
                    //operationsReviewLevels.Add(new OperationsReviewLevel(currentEntry["Review Level Title"].ToString(), currentEntry["Reviewer IDs"].ToString(), (int)currentEntry["Review Level Priority"]));
                }
```

If you're not using SharePoint online,make sure the fields match also.

Comment: It is SharePoint online, but unfortunately this did not resolve my error